# google Places autocomplete api works everywhere but subdomain

Tags: javascript, iis, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am running into an issue with the google places autocomplete API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I have generated a key and have it unrestricted.  It works just fine on my local machine. It also works on the companies production server.

however,  when we place the exact same code on a certain website on a subdomain it simply does not work.

The site has a SSL certificate,  and everything else is running just fine, but the code listed simply will not work.  There are no errors in the server logs,  inspecting the element with chrome reveals nothing.  there are no error messages from the chrome console.

I wish I could provide a URL, but the company will not allow it, and I am also highly restricted on what details I can provide.

Here are the details I can provide about the server:
Windows Server 2012 R2
Version 6.2(Build 9200)
Internet Information Service (Version 8.5.9600.1638)

Comment: Check browser console. Post any error related the API here. It could allowed referers

Comment: That the thing.  I try using it and there are not any browser console errors.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue was the key being used.  Despite the key not having any restrictions it would not work on the domain in question.  After generating a new key and using it.  It started working on that site.